# Can I create a Campaign using the API only in Marketo?

Tags: marketo

I know I cant create a campaign on web browser, but I must do it only on the codes.
Do you have any good idea?
I'm sorry I'm bigginer of English and technology:(

Comment: I know I can do it like https://docs.marketo.com/display/public/DOCS/Create+a+Campaign but I can't use it...

Answer (score 0):

Marketo does not provide a way to create programs or campaigns from [the api](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/asset-endpoint-reference/#/). They must be created within the user interface. The level of complexity within a campaign would make it unwieldy to create from an api. You can list the campaign metadata, and activate/deactivate campaigns, but that's about it.